# Printing maps at a specific scale using the print composer (1"=2000')

Tags: qgis, scale

I have created my map for land planning and set up my sheet to be exported in the print composer, but I'm confused when it comes to printing at a certain scale. I see within the item properties > main properties that there is a tab for "scale" but I have no idea what unit of measurement it is displaying at.

I have attached images of my coordinate system and general settings for reference, and in the case of this project I am looking to create a basemap at a scale of 1"=2000'.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale is given as a unitless ratio. For example, a scale of 1:5000 is the same as 1" = 5000."  It's also the same as 1 m = 5000 m or 1 yard = 5000 yards. If you want a scale of 1" = X' you will have to convert feet to inches.

> 2000 ft = 2000 ft * 12 in / ft =  24,000 in

So a scale of 1"=2000' is the same as 1:24,000

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270145/display-numeric-scale-in-two-different-units-eg-1-inch-1000-feet