# Display numeric scale in two different units, eg 1 inch = 1000 feet

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

How do I display a numeric scale for a map in two units, for example
1 in = 1000 ft ?

I know it's possible to display a scale bar as "Numeric," which provides only a ratio, in this example 1:12,000.

It seems like it should be possible to insert an expression into a label, only I can't figure out how to reference a map item in the expression builder. The map item has a variable "map_scale" but when I put this variable into a text item, it just displays as a string. [image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232715/113585  If you just added "/12" at the end of the expression calling the custom function, it'll give you feet for whatever scale you're at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible in QGIS print composer to include a numeric scale in an html box?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/is-it-possible-in-qgis-print-composer-to-include-a-numeric-scale-in-an-html-box)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @JoshC. It took a bit of work to figure out since I'm very new to using python in QGIS, but once I figured out how to implement the solution to that question, it was very simple to adapt to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the custom python function provided in the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/is-it-possible-in-qgis-print-composer-to-include-a-numeric-scale-in-an-html-box), then divide by 12 to get inch:feet ratio.

Step 1: Add a text label to the print composer

Step 2: Insert an expression into the label

[image]

Step 3: Create a custom function
In the "Insert Expression" window, click the "Function Editor" tab. Click "New File," enter the file name get_composer_map_scale, click OK. Copy and paste the code on [this page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/is-it-possible-in-qgis-print-composer-to-include-a-numeric-scale-in-an-html-box), then click "Load" to register the custom function. 
[image]

Step 4: Use the custom function to display the scale as the ratio [inches on the page]:[feet in real life]

[image]

Copy/paste into your label:

> 1 inch = [%round(get_composer_map_scale( '**Composer 1**')/12, 0)%] feet

Substituting the name of your print composer where it says Composer 1.

Note: I added the function round(value, places) to round to an integer value of feet. To display more digits, substitute the number of digits for the zero.

EDIT: This answer only works for QGIS 2. For QGIS 3, see this answer: gis.stackexchange.com/a/332759/35561. Thanks to [@MrChe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35561/mr-che) for the suggestion.

Comment: Only for QGIS 2.

Comment: For QGIS 3. To insert current map's scale value in label as text see this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/332759/35561